# MeanPredictionBands not working in ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"]

Tags: fitting, parametric-functions

I have a problem creating `MeanPredictionBands` for a `FittedModel` from the `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"]` if the `FittedModel` includes `ParametricFunctions`.
A simple example:

```
data1 = {#, 0.05 E^(0.075 #)} & /@ Range[10];
data2 = {#, 0.075 E^(0.075 #)} & /@ Range[10];

model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == u x[t], x[0] == x0}, x, {t, 0, 100}, {u, x0}];

fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][{data1, 
   data2}, {model[u, x0][t], model[u, x02][t]}, {u, x0, x02}, {t}];

fit["ParameterTable"];
fit["MeanPredictionBands"]

Experimental`NumericalFunction::nnum: The function value Switch[Round[\[FormalN]],1,<<1>>,2,ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>],0,1,False,{{u$214682,x0$214683},System`Utilities`HashTable[<3>],{},{},{1,2},{Automatic,0,0},{0,1}},{NDSolve`base$214690,NDSolve`NDSolveParametricFunction[0,{ParametricNDSolveValue,Internal`Bag[<2>],None,ParametricNDSolveValue},<<7>>,{},<<1>>]}][u,x02][t]] is not a number at {u,x0,x02} = {0.0749998,0.0499999,0.0749999}.
```

The `MultiNonlinearModelFit` works and gives a good solution in the ParameterTable, but the `fit[MeanPredictionBands]` gives an error. It seems that the issue is with the ParametricFunction in the FittedModel. I have been able to get the MeanPredictionBands for a FittedModel from the MultiNonlinearModelFit if it does not contain ParametricFunctions. How can I get the mean prediction bands in this case?

Comment: Please add the text of the error you get by editing your question.

Comment: Note that `MultiNonlinearModelFit` only allows (at least the last time I looked) a common error variance.  While estimates of parameters might not be affected so much, if the error variance of the different models differ, then the prediction bands can be greater affected.  Your example above has no error term for either model which doesn't make for a very realistic proxy for your real data.

Comment: Thank you JimB. My real data have usually multiple measurements for each point and I weigh the data with the variance. Mostly my models are very similar and typically only vary in initial conditions, and I expect similar error variance in the models.

Comment: @JimB `MultiNonlinearModelFit` allows for different weights to be applied to each individual data point across the different datasets. You need to specify them as `Weights -> {{w11, w12, ...}, {w21, w22, ...}, ...}`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit (Preface:  As stated below `MultiNonlinearModelFit` is great.)  Using the `Weight` option will allow for independent errors with different variances but only if one "knows" the ratios of the variances.  In biological applications it's almost certainly wishful thinking that one knows the ratios and that the errors would be independent.  So it's about the "ability to assume" rather than the "willingness to assume".  I would hope that someday `NonlinearModelFit` and `LinearModelFit` would allow for mixed models (i.e., models with more than one error term and correlated errors).

Comment: @JimB Do you have a source about the sort of models you have in mind?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yes:  it is the infamous lme4 in R (for linear models) along with PROC MIXED from SAS (for linear models) and PROC NLMIXED from SAS (nonlinear models).  As you already know, mixed models are notorious for numerical instability and therefore very difficult to write code that works for a variety of models and input data.

Comment: @JimB I really don't know the implementation details for those models, so I don't think I can add something like that to my resource function unfortunately. It's probably something that would need to be done in the core language. But I'll keep it in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 4):

It appears as though `NonlinearModelFit`/`FittedModel` are unable to compute the required gradients themselves, so you'll have to update the definition of `MultiNonlinearModelFit`:

```
Options[MultiNonlinearModelFit] = {AccuracyGoal->Automatic,ConfidenceLevel->19/20,EvaluationMonitor->None,Gradient->Automatic,MaxIterations->Automatic,
    Method->Automatic,PrecisionGoal->Automatic,StepMonitor->None,Tolerance->Automatic,VarianceEstimatorFunction->Automatic,
    Weights->Automatic, WorkingPrecision->Automatic, "DatasetIndexSymbol"->\[FormalN]
}; (* \[Equal] Join[Options[NonlinearModelFit], {"DatasetIndexSymbol" -> \[FormalN]}] *)

MultiNonlinearModelFit[datasets_, form_, fitParams_, independents : Except[_List], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    MultiNonlinearModelFit[datasets, form, fitParams, {independents}, opts];
 
MultiNonlinearModelFit[datasets_, form : Except[_?AssociationQ], fitParams_, independents_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    MultiNonlinearModelFit[datasets, <|"Expressions" -> form, "Constraints" -> True|>, fitParams, independents, opts];
 
MultiNonlinearModelFit[
    datasets : {__?(MatrixQ[#1, NumericQ] &)}, 
    assoc : KeyValuePattern[{
        "Expressions" -> expressions_,
        "Constraints" -> constraints_
    }] /; AssociationQ[assoc],
    fitParams_List, 
    independents_List,
    opts : OptionsPattern[]
] := Module[{
    fitfun, weights,
    numSets = Length[datasets],
    precision = Precision @ datasets,
    augmentedData,
    indexSymbol = OptionValue["DatasetIndexSymbol"],
    grad
},
    augmentedData = Join @@ MapIndexed[
        Join[ConstantArray[N[#2, precision], Length[#1]], #1, 2]&,
        datasets
    ];
    fitfun = With[{
        conditions = Flatten @ Map[
            {#, Indexed[expressions, #]}&, 
            Range[numSets]
        ]
    }, 
        Switch @@ Prepend[conditions, Round[indexSymbol]]
    ];
    grad=D[fitfun, {Replace[fitParams, {v_, ___} :> v , 1]}];
    weights = Replace[
        OptionValue[Weights],
        {
            (list_List)?(VectorQ[#1, NumericQ]& ) /; Length[list] === numSets :> 
                Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {list, Length /@ datasets}], 
            list : {__?(VectorQ[#1, NumericQ] & )} /; Length /@ list === Length /@ datasets :>
                Join @@ list, 
            "InverseLengthWeights" :> Join @@ Map[
                ConstantArray[N[1 / #1, precision], #1]&,
                Length /@ datasets
            ]
        }
    ]; 
    NonlinearModelFit[
        augmentedData,
        If[TrueQ[constraints], fitfun, {fitfun, constraints}], 
        fitParams,
        Flatten[{indexSymbol, independents}],
        Weights -> weights, 
        Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NonlinearModelFit]],
        Gradient->grad
    ]
];
```

This is copied almost straight from the definition notebook of `MultiNonlinearModelFit` (available via `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit", "DefinitionNotebook"]`, except that I manually supply the gradient of the function:

I compute it as (thanks @SjoerdSmit for the significant simplification!)

```
grad=D[fitfun, {Replace[fitParams, {v_, ___} :> v , 1]}];
```

This is effectively computing the gradients of each fit function separately and combining them using the same `Switch[Round[...], ...]` strategy that `MultiNonlinearModelFit` is using for the fitting itself.

The gradient is then supplied to `NonlinearModelFit` in the last expression, which means we can now compute the prediction bands:

```
fit["MeanPredictionBands"]
```

[image]

We can now insert a value for the formal index to select the bands for one of the functions:

```
data1 = {#, 0.05 E^(0.075 #) + 0.005 RandomReal[]} & /@ Range[10];
data2 = {#, 0.075 E^(0.075 #)} & /@ Range[10];

model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == u x[t], x[0] == x0}, 
   x, {t, 0, 100}, {u, x0}];

fit = MultiNonlinearModelFit[{data1, data2}, {model[u, x0][t], 
    model[u, x02][t]}, {u, x0, x02}, {t}];

Show[Plot[
  fit["MeanPredictionBands"] /. \[FormalN] -> 1 // Evaluate, {t, 0, 
   10}, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> 1 -> {2}], ListPlot[data1]]
```

[image]

(Note that I have added some noise to `data1` to make the bands visible)

Comment: Thank you Lukas, I need to study the definition a bit more but your solution looks good. I find the MultiNonlinearModelFit function very useful, and with the explicit "grad" definition you used, I hope to be able to use the "MeanPredictionBands" for a wider set of FittedModels.

Comment: +1 for the modification of `MultiNonlinearModelFit` (and despite my multiple complaints  about `MultiNonlinearModelFit`, it is wonderfully constructed and useful function).  However, that single complaint I have ("assuming a common error variance") results in this case with the resulting prediction interval being too small for `data1` and too large for `data2`.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! Is there a reason for not just computing the gradient with `grad = D[fitfun, {Replace[fitParams, {v_, ___} :> v , {1}]}]`? It seems to give the exact same results for me that way.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Not really - I could have sworn that I first tried something like that, but evidently, I failed. I can't see a reason why it should ever fail. Thanks!